# How Can I Disable Spesific Hotkeys With GSettings in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, gsettings

I could not find the right schema and commands to disable hotkeys in Ubuntu with `gsettings`.

How can I disable some hotkeys? For example if I want to disable <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> what command should I use on terminal?

Comment: are you using xubuntu? or Ubuntu? what is your distro.

Comment: @UnKNOWn ubuntu 20.04 focal

Answer (score 0):

the one, you mentioned is

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
```

Example:

```
[admin@ADMIN ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']
[admin@ADMIN ~]$
```

above results two combinations, so remove the one you dont need with below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
```

to revert back above change, run below command in need.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
```

Comment: I did this but did not work, I still can switch the applications with ALT+TAB. Is that correct: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"

Comment: What is the output of first command in above post?

Comment: The output comes [] but it still works. May be it is because of my desktop environment. My ubuntu has Unity desktop, not gnome.

Comment: Oh Ok.. then ignore my comments.. Lets see anyone with Unity DE will respond..